# Eclipse Force.com IDE cannot create project

Tags: eclipse, error-messages, force.com-ide

I am getting the following error when I try to create a New Force.com project:

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.salesforce.ide.ui was unable to load class com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCreateWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.salesforce.ide.ui (976).

That library is definitely there... it seems like probably a load order issue? Someone else had the same issue, and no one responded to their post.

I have tried: 
Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) - both EE and Java. 
Java Version: JDK 9.0.1 
both 64 bit.

Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Force.com IDE   38.0.0.201701101558

I've been using Eclipse for ~8 years with Salesforce and have never had an issue - and just spent 4 hours trying to get this to work. Please help!

Thanks,
Sara

Comment: Force.com plugin on some eclipse versions can be buggy, give different one a try.

Answer (score 1):

I simply couldn't get it to work trying everything I could think of, so I downgraded to Java JDK8 and it worked fine.

Comment: Haha, I too tied to install eclipse today as my illuminated cloud/Intelli-j license got expired. I came back to post the update here, I wish I should have seen your answer before. What a waste of 2 sweet hours :(